# Is it bad practice to use pseudo elements for creating content?

Tags: html, css

I'm just wondering some time when i'm creating stuff with html/css it's easier for me to use pseudo like `:after` or `:before` for inserting content.
To make some small tooltips arrows or something like small image icon.
Is it bad practice to work like this?
 I'm currently working in a place that i don't have access to the html.
It's done by JAVA developer with GWT. And we found our self (the front-end developers) with alot of time solving things with pseudo elements because the html is pretty lame.
After a while i'm founding myself in my own personal project making alot of pseudo elements in cases that i don't really have to do this. 
So it's coming to my mind if this habit is a bad thing that i need to avoid from?

Comment: "Bad practice" is a matter of opinion. But you should ensure that the page still contains the equivalent information available to users who cannot see the screen, and therefore use screen readers to get that information.